# Delete Duplicate using SPARK SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

The following code works fine in the Databricks Spark SQL

```
with CTE1 as
(
 select *,
        row_number()over(Partition by ID order by Name) as r
 from Emp
)
select * from CTE1 where r>1
```

But for the `DELETE` statement:

```
with CTE1 as
(
 select *,
        row_number()over(Partition by ID order by Name) as r
 from Emp
)

DELETE from CTE1 where r>1
```

there is an Error in SQL statement :

> Analysis exception: Table Not found Emp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you want is only available in SQL Server.  Assuming that `Name` is unique and not `NULL`, you can use an alternative method such as this:

```
delete from emp
    where name > (select min(emp2.name)
                  from emp emp2
                  where emp2.id = emp.id
                 );
```

Otherwise, use the table's primary key for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it,instead of deleting, just select what you want

```
with CTE1 as
(
 select *,
        row_number()over(Partition by ID order by Name) as r
 from Emp
) where r=1
```